# SetState based on manipulated prop with hooks

Tags: reactjs

How do I `setState` on a functional component with a manipulated prop with hooks before the page load?

On a class component I would do something like:

```
export default class Editable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const {clients} = this.props

    this.state = {
      columns: [
        {title: 'test', field: 'test'},
        {
          title: 'test2',
          field: 'test'
        }
      ],
      data: clients.map((client) => ({
        test: client.test,
        test2: client.test2,
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return
        (...)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `useState` - this is only be used once.
Keep in mind that you will need to use `useEffect` hook in order to change your state like you would have done with e.g. `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
const initialColumns = [
  { title: "test", field: "test" },
  { title: "test2", field: "test" }
];

const Test = props => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(initialColumns);
  const [data, setData] = useState(
    props.clients.map(client => ({
      test: client.test,
      test2: client.test2
    }))
  );

return (...)
};
```

Just have a look at the console logging in Test.js here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mcclintock-041qx